# ios stringWithContentsOfURL with encoding?

Tags: ios

I have a problem using "stringWithContentsOfURL" to get source page of a web(chinese)
Thinking using "NSUTF8StringEncoding" but didn't work(got null for result). My code looks like this

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.morningstar.com.tw/download_pdf_2-1.aspx"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"html = %@",string);

replaced "NSUTF8StringEncoding" by "NSASCIIStringEncoding", did get a result but words are scrambled.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need a different encoding:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseTrad);
```

You can also use `kCFStringEncodingDOSChineseSimplif` for simplified chinese. Use `encoding` in place of `NSASCIIStringEncoding` or the other standard ones.

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211-CH2g-BCIHAEFA) for more encodings if these do not work properly.

Comment: Thanks Evan Mulawski, that's exactly what i am looking for!